# D3 custom library - Collapsible Tree in Drupal 7

Tags: d3.js, drupal-7

I am trying to create VIEWS for my TAXONOMIES like this - Collapsible Tree (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).

I installed D3 modules, imported all the D3 libraries and then I started to create a custom library. I created d3.[mynewlibrary].libraries.info file, [mynewlibrary].css and [mynewlibrary].js and uploaded under d3.[mynewlibrary] folder. However, I went back to VIEWS and couldn't be able to select [mynewlibrary].

I wonder what would be the best way to validate my codes written in my custom library and if the VIEWS will automatically add the new custom library for selection.

I am new to D3. Can anyone provide some help?

Here below are my js and css codes. Thanks!

```js
/**
 *@file
 *Javascript for D3 Collapsible Tree Library.
 */

(function($) {

Drupal.d3.collapsibletree = function (select, setting) {

   var vis = d3.select("#viz").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", 400)
      .attr("height", 300)
      .append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(40, 0)"); // shift everything to the right
 
      // Create a tree "canvas"
      var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([300,150]);
 
      var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
      // change x and y (for the left to right tree)
      .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
 
      // Preparing the data for the tree layout, convert data into an array of nodes
      var nodes = tree.nodes(treeData);
      // Create an array with all the links
      var links = tree.links(nodes);
 
      console.log(treeData)
      console.log(nodes)
      console.log(links)
 
      var link = vis.selectAll("pathlink")
      .data(links)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal)
 
      var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
 
      // Add the dot at every node
      node.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 3.5);
 
      // place the name atribute left or right depending if children
      node.append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...
Without seeing your other files (.info), I can't be sure. But even if some of the JS is broken, this visualization should show up as an option in Views.

Are all your dependencies and versions  correctly called in the .info file?

Comment: Here below is my .info file.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = Collapsible Tree
description = D3 example Collapsible Tree library
files[js][] = collapsibletree.js
files[css][] = collapsibletree.css
version = 0.1
dependencies[] = d3.extend
dependencies[] = d3.tooltip
views[version] = 3.0
views[fields][rows][__data_type] = 2dnnv
views[fields][x_label][type] = string
views[settings] = views-settings.php
```